# Java Google App Engine: What does @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY) do/mean?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I just started learning server/database stuff on Java, and I was wondering what the piece of code `@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)`
means/does. I am using Google's App Engine

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a Java [annotation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) defining the strategy the annotated  entity will use to be persisted.

It means, that, for instance if you have a  `class Employee`, it will be persistent, and the way its primary key will be generated, will be with a mechanism called `IDENTITY` which automatically creates the next value for you.

All this part of an API called [Java Persistence API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2EE/jpa/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the references!